# Why define $\gcd(r,s)$ as a positive generator $d$ of the cyclic group $H=\{nr+ms|n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, divisibility, cyclic-groups

This is in regards to definition 6.8, p. 62 from Fraleigh's "A first course in abstract algebra".

> **6.8 Definition**
>
> Let $r$ and $s$ be two positive integers. The positive generator $d$ of the cyclic group $$H=\{nr+ms|n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$ under addition is the **greatest common divisor** (abbreviated gcd) of $r$ and $s$. We write $d=\gcd(r,s)$
>
> Note from the definition that $d$ is a divisor of both $r$ and $s$ since both $r=1r+0s$ and $s=0r+1s$ are in $H$. Since $d\in H$, we can write $$d=nr+ms$$ for some integer $n$ and $m$. We see that every integer dividing both $r$ and $s$ divides the right hand side of the equation, and hence must be a divisor of $d$ also. Thus $d$ must be the largest number dividing both $r$ and $s$; this accounts for the name given to $d$ in Definition 6.8.

Basically I don't understand this definition at all, and I am hoping someone can break it down for me why it makes sense.

For example:

> "$d$ is a divisor of both $r$ and $s$ since both $r=1r+0s$ and $s=0r+1s$ are in $H$"

$d$ is a generator so $\langle d\rangle=H$, but I don't see why $d$ should be a divisor of $r$ and $s$.

Why does $H$ have anything to do with divisors? If you wrote out $\{d^n|n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ why would it contain divisors for $r,s$? Is every element a divisor, or just some of the elements?

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain the gist of this.

Comment: You shouldn't write $\{\,d^n\mid n\in\mathbb Z\,\}$ because we are talking about subgroups of $\mathbb Z$, i.e. a group that is wiritten additively. Therefore rather write $\{\,nd\mid n\in\mathbb Z\,\}$, which is thus precisely the set of all multiples of $d$.

Comment: The definition is a bit pushed in. A bit of motivation could help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H = r\mathbb{Z} + s\mathbb{Z} $ .

$H$ is a subgroup, i.e. an ideal of  $\mathbb{Z}$, which is a PID, and so $H = <d> =d\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. the cyclic group generated by $d$, for some $d \in \mathbb{N}$ .

$r, s \in H$ , so $d \mid r $ and $d \mid s$ by the definition of cyclic group. Moreover if $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is such that $k \mid r $ and $k \mid s$ this means that $r = ka $ and $s = kb $ for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $$H = r\mathbb{Z} + s\mathbb{Z} = ka\mathbb{Z} + kb\mathbb{Z}\subseteq k\mathbb{Z}$$ $$H = d\mathbb{Z} \subseteq k\mathbb{Z}$$ and so $k \mid d$ . But this is precisely the "elementary "definition of greatest common divisor, and so $$d = \gcd(r,s)$$

Comment: I understand up until "Moreover". Why is it so that $H\subseteq k\mathbb{Z}$? Can you elaborate on this part? Please don't hesitate to explicitly state facts or observations that seem obvious.

Comment: Specifically, I don't understand from the definition why $d$ must be the largest number dividing both $r$ and $s$.

Comment: @john.abraham: I have edited to answer your first question; for your second question, if $d\mathbb{Z} \subseteq k\mathbb{Z}$ then it means that $d = kn $ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ because $ d \in d\mathbb{Z} \subseteq k\mathbb{Z}$ and so $ k \mid d $

Comment: I agree that $k|d$, but I don't understand why $k$ is the largest divisor and not just any divisor. Take the definition: "We see that every integer dividing both $r$ and $s$ divides the right hand side of the equation, and hence must be a divisor of d also. **Thus** $d$ must be the largest number dividing both $r$ and $s$." I don't understand this "thus" - why does it follow? Maybe there is some fact about numbers or division I am missing? I don't see the connection between the last sentence of the definition and the preceding ones.

Comment: @john.abraham: The answer to your question is in my proof, between "Moreover if k $\in \mathbb{N}$ " to "$k \mid d$" . If $k \mid d$ obviously $d \geq k$

Comment: When you use $\subseteq$, do you mean subset or subgroup?

Comment: @john.abraham: subgroup

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain, it really helped; finally it makes sense :)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that 
$$H=r\Bbb Z+ s\Bbb Z$$
is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ but we know that every subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ take the form $n\Bbb Z$ so there's a unique $d>0$ such that
$$H=d\Bbb Z$$
and then we define the $\gcd(r,s)$ to be this number $d$.